# Prove that disk automorphism of parabolic and hyperbolic types are conformally equivalent to some certain automorphisms respectively.

Tags: automorphism-group

The automorphisms of the open unit disk $\mathbb{D}=\{z \in \mathbb{C}:|z|<1\}$ are precisely the analytic bijections on $\mathbb{D}$ which have the form $$\varphi(z)=\lambda \frac{a-z}{1-\bar{a} z}.$$

where $\lambda$ is a unimodular constant and $a$ is a point in $\mathbb{D}$. These automorphisms form a group under composition denoted by Aut(D). Every element of Aut(D) has two fixed points (counting multiplicity), and thus can be classified by the location of the fixed points:

- **elliptic**: one fixed point in $\mathbb{D}$ and one in the complement of $\overline{\mathbb{D}}$;
- **parabolic**: one fixed point on the unit circle $\partial \mathbb{D}$ (of multiplicity 2);
- **hyperbolic**: two distinct fixed points on $\partial \mathbb{D}$.

Two disk automorphisms $\varphi$ and $\psi$ are **conformally equivalent** if there exists a disk automorphism $\tau$ for which $\psi=\tau \circ \varphi \circ \tau^{-1}$.

As *Composition Operators on Spaces of Analytic Functions* by C.Cowen says in  Page59, exercise 2.3.5:

> Let $\varphi$ be an elliptic disk automorphism with fixed point $a$ in $\mathbb{D}$. Then $\varphi$ is conformally equivalent to $\psi(z)=\lambda z$ where $\lambda=\varphi^{\prime}(a)$.

> Let $\varphi$ be a hyperbolic disk automorphism. Then $\varphi$ is conformally equivalent to $\psi(z)=\frac{z+r}{1+r z}$ for some $r \in(0,1)$.

> Let $\varphi$ be a parabolic disk automorphism. Then $\varphi$ is conformally equivalent to either $\psi_1(z)=\frac{(1+i) z-1}{z+i-1}$ or $\psi_2(z)=\frac{(1-i) z-1}{z-i-1}$.

As for the elliptic type, since the fixed point belongs to the open disk, it's not that hard to prove. But for the other two types, I have no idea how to prove them because the fixed points belong to $\partial \mathbb{D}$ and I have searched on google and StackExchange without finding any articles or books which are relevant to these two propositions.

Any hints or any articles or books (which is available online) will be highly appreciated! Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

John Milnor (*Dynamics in one complex variable*, problem 1.d) mentions that but for automorphisms of $\mathbb{H}$ of the form $z\mapsto \frac{az+b}{cz+d}$ with $ad-bd \neq 0 $ . It is claimed that:

> Every automorphism without fixed point is conjugate to a unique tranformation of the form $z\mapsto z+1$ or $z\mapsto z-1$ or $z\mapsto \lambda z$ with $|\lambda|>1 $.

> Finally, if the automorphism $g$ has a fixed point $\omega_0 \in \mathbb{H}$, then is uniquely determined by the derivative $g'(\omega_0)$.

Knowing, that an automorphism $f$ of $\mathbb{H}$ with $\omega_0$ as a fixed point coresponds to rotation in the disk, we can compose by a biholomorphism form $\mathbb{H}\rightarrow\mathbb{D}$ sending $z\mapsto \frac{z-i}{z+i}$ and after by its inverse map $\mathbb{D} \rightarrow \mathbb{H}$ sending $z\mapsto \frac{i(z+1)}{1-z}$, we find that $f$ is in the form $z\mapsto \frac{z(ie^{i\theta}+i)+e^{i\theta}-1}{z(1-e^{i\theta})+i+ie^{i\theta}}$.

That's all i founded.
Thank you if you find mistakes.

Comment: Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

I think I have the answer for the hyperbolic case. Knowing that $\mathbb{D}\cong\mathbb{H}$, I think it is easier to deal with $\text{Aut}(\mathbb{H})\cong PSL_2(\mathbb{R})=SL_2(R)/\{\pm id\}$, because we can work with matrices. One can check (it is a simple fixed point calculus) that we have the folowing correspondence:

- An elliptic automorphism corresponds to a class of matrices represented by $A\in PSL_2(\mathbb{R})$ such that $|\text{Tr}(A)|<2$.
- A parabollic automorphism verifies $|\text{Tr}(A)|=2$.
- A hyperbolic automorphism satisfies $|\text{Tr}(A)|>2$.

By "conjugating" by the biholomorphism $\mathbb{H}\to\mathbb{D}$ sending $z\mapsto \frac{az+b}{cz+d}$, we find that $\psi$ corresponds to the homotethie $z\mapsto \lambda z$ with $\lambda\in (1,+\infty)$. So let's take $h\in \text{Aut}(\mathbb{H})$ represented by $A=\begin{pmatrix} a & b\\ c & d \end{pmatrix}\in PSL_2(\mathbb{R})$. The characteristic polynomial of $A$ is given by $X^2+X(-\text{Tr}(A))+\det(A)$. As $\Delta=\text{Tr}^2(A)-4>0$, this gives that $A$ can be written in diagonal form. So there exists $P\in GL_2
(\mathbb{R})$ such that $PAP^{-1}=\begin{pmatrix} \alpha & 0\\ 0 & \beta \end{pmatrix}$ with $\alpha\neq\beta$.

But we want to know if actually we can take $P\in SL_2(\mathbb{R})$. There arises two cases:

- If $\det(P)>0$ we considere the matrix $\tilde P:= \frac{1}{\sqrt{\det(P))}}P\in SL_2(\mathbb{R})$.
- If $\det(P)<0$ we considere the matrix $\tilde P:= P \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1\\ 1 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$ and we get $\det(\tilde{P})>0$ so we can do the same trick like above.

To finish the proof, the matrix \begin{pmatrix} \alpha & 0\\ 0 & \beta \end{pmatrix} corresponds to the automorphism sending $z\mapsto \frac{\alpha}{\beta}z$. If $\alpha<\beta$, we conjugate by $z\mapsto -\frac{1}{z}$.

I'm working on the parabolic case.

Comment: Thank you so much for your work!